# Copy kendo grid item containing xml and Json to clipboard with formatting through javascript

Tags: javascript, copy, kendo-grid, clipboarddata

I'm stuck in a problem, I have a grid that contains an item which can contain Json or XML. I need this data to be copied on the clipboard. Below is my code that i'm using to copy the content. It's basically setting the value of a hidden field and then copying the data from that field to the clipboard. What I'm stuck with is the data is being copied as a string and i want to have it copied in proper JSON formatting is there a way to achieve this? I have tried and none of these work.

```
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, "\t"); 

JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, 4);
```

Below is the my copy function.

```
    function CopyData(e) {
        var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var newItem = this.dataItem(tr);
        $('#ContentTypeField').val(newItem.Content);
        var copyText = document.getElementById("ContentTypeField");
        copyText.type = 'text';
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
        /* Copy the text inside the text field */
        document.execCommand("copy");
        copyText.type = 'hidden';
}
```

and my grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<App.Models.ViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Width(240).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(280);2
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Width(440);
        columns.Command(command => {command.Custom("Content").Click("CopyData"); }).Width(150);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create().Text("Add");
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Content.cshtml"))
     .Pageable(pager => pager
        .Input(true)
        .Numeric(true)
        .Info(true)
        .PreviousNext(true)
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
      )
    .Sortable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_AppSetting"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
            model.Field(s => s.Name);
            model.Field(s => s.Description);
        })
        .Read("Read", "App")
        .Update(c => c.Action("Update", "App"))
        .Destroy(c => c.Action("Delete", "App"))
        .Create(c => c.Action("Create", "App"))
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used clipboard API to achieve this. It takes the text as parameter since in the previous method I was setting value of a hidden field and then copying it to the clipboard which changed the formatting. Below is the code on how I did it.

```
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(grid.fields.Content).then(function () {
        alert('successfully copied!');
                }, 
    function () {
    alert ('Copy to clipboard failed');
});
```